# Is there a free Statistics Package for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, r, statistics, sas

Is there an open source and/or free statistics package or library for [Delphi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_programming_language)? I'm looking for something that can compile directly into the executable, so no DLL's. It needs to be compatible with Delphi 2009 and later (the Unicode versions).

Hopefully there is something comprehensive available out there. By comparison, I am used to the amazing features of [SAS](http://www.sas.com/technologies/analytics/statistics/stat/index.html) and [R](http://www.r-project.org/).

I'm looking for distribution functions (normal, binomial, chi square, [logit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit)) and regression (linear, non-linear, multinomial) and if possible predictors (e.g. [ARIMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average)).

Comment: Why must it be free?  MtxVec is an exceptionally good math library for Delphi, and has a stats-based addon module.   Should I provide a more detailed answer about it, or is commercial software not for any consideration?  Why no DLLs?   Many math libraries ship with optimized BLAS and LAPACK DLLs, MtxVec being no exception.

Comment: Free because I really only need a few functions. Okay, I'll go up to $50 or $100. But please not $500. No DLLs because my application now ships as a single executable. For these few functions, I don't want to change that.

Comment: If your software is for education purposes then "The trial versions of all our products (MtxVec, FFT Properties, Dew Math Library, Dew Lab Studio) can be used for unlimited time, if used for educational purposes. ".  But you probably would have mentioned that, I guess.

Comment: Just to point out that just like C, Delphi can also directly talk to R; translated R headers are available here: https://github.com/swissr/rpascal

Comment: @PhiS is there any instructions to use this R headers, so call R functions on Delphi?

Comment: @Artur_Indio There are instructions, but they aren't Delphi-specific. Perhaps start by looking at the R internals documentation: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html - aimed at C programmers. You can essentially do the same in Delphi using the translated R headers (just with different syntax). One small caveat: you may have to change [P]Char to [P]AnsiChar in the headers for modern Delphi versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a large but somewhat out of date list [here](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/MathFunctions/StatisticsAndProbability.htm#Sources). I've never seen anything as comprehensive as SAS or R, however. Then again, SAS and R are more comprehensive than most stats packages for *any* language.

Comment: This answer includes the TPMath that skamradt mentions.

Comment: ... but I wish there were something newer.

Comment: Any tutorial on how to call R functions from Delphi?

Answer (score 6):

The library [here](http://www.unilim.fr/pages_perso/jean.debord/tpmath/tpmath.htm) might be of some help, although I admit I never used the statistic functions so will not be able to vouch for them. You are probably not going to run into many compatibility problems with most of these math libraries, since most of the Unicode changes revolved around strings and characters, not the numerical types.

Comment: I've used TPMath a lot, including the statistical functions, and have never had any problems with it. It contains many of the standard statistics functions, but may not contain more "obscure" ones (e.g., I remember there are no functions for Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests included).